# Laravel: How to Flush Session and Redirect on Logout?

Tags: php, laravel-routing, laravel-7

I'm trying to flush the session then redirect the user to the "activate" view on logout, but it keeps taking me to "login" instead. Here's what I've tried in my web.php routes file:

```
Route::get('/logout', function () {
    Session::flush();
    Auth::logout();
    return Redirect::to('activate');
});
```

How do I flush the cache and take users to the "activate" page on logout?

Comment: If you're also using the boilerplate auth routes make sure this route comes before that since they conflict

Comment: No I'm not using boiler plate. Should I place this route at the top of my web.php?

Comment: If ´activate´ requires to be logged in, the redirection will keep on redirecting the user to the login page. Make sure you redirect to a page that doesn't require a login.

Answer (score 1):

Change your route url, or except it from `AuthController` constructor :

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['logout']]);
}
```